# Is there a way in Windows/GNU Linux to prevent burn-in on plasma TVs being used as a monitor?

Tags: linux, windows, hdtv, burn-in, plasma-tv

I've got a plasma TV (Samsung E8000) that I'm using as a second monitor for my Windows 7 computer (also be interested in software for GNU/Linux).

Since plasma TVs have problems with burn-in, manufacturers advise against having static images on the screen for 20+ minutes.

While I mostly use the TV for playing TV or Movies in fullscreen, I would prefer to be able to put my browser on it (or other programs) as needed without worrying if I'll forget it and leave it up there for too long. While the TV I have has features for preventing burn in (such as periodically shifting pixels up to roughly 10? can't remember exactly), this wouldn't really help with a browser interface, and a webpage that has a solid background.

What I am looking for is a way of maybe flashing a specified monitor every (specified amount of time).

Is there software out there for Windows or GNU/Linux, or some setting in either, that could accomplish this?

Comment: this was originally the reason "ScreenSavers" were invented. is there some reason that they are not sufficient for your needs? keep in mind, makeing a small change to the screen every x seconds or whatever will not help with burnin. you need to change the full screen to some other image regularly so that no point on the screen "gets used" to what its displaying. auto-powering down the monitor is also effective.

Comment: I'm looking for a way that it would only affect one monitor.  I might be working on my primary monitor while a static image is up on my Plasma TV, which would prevent the screensaver from starting.

Answer (score 1):

There are many snow creating software that may fit your need. One of them is [DesktopSnowOK](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/DesktopSnowOK) which is a light portable free software. But more importantly, it isn't a screensaver so even if you're working, surfing the web or doing anything else, the screen is always protected by moving snows. It can also show falling leaves and uses very few CPU resource

[image: DesktopSnowOK with 2000 snowflakes]

Another alternative: [Desktop Christmas Snow 1.0](https://www.freewarefiles.com/Desktop-Christmas-Snow_program_94720.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a full screen music visualizer and mute the program

That's what I have been trying to do but for some reason on my system Rhythmbox freezes when I tell it to full screen the visualizer (I'm planning on using it to listen to music, and I like Rhythmbox's interface and would rather not have another program open just to visualise...) but I think that's what I will have to